# What is wrong with this javascript codes

Tags: javascript, json, openstreetmap

see the code.
Thanks for the help everyone. Much appreciated for the valuable feedback. But it haven't helped. I really thank you.

```
   
      $.get("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=pekin,+china&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1").done(function(data)
        {
            var aJsonData = new Array();
            var iBiggest = 0;

            aJsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            aData = aJsonData;

            for(var i=0; i < aData.length; i++)
            {
                if(i != 0)
                {
                    if((aData[i].polygonpoints.length) > (aData[iBiggest].polygonpoints.length))
                    {
                        iBiggest = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            alert(iBiggest);

            for(var j=0; j < aData[iBiggest].polygonpoints.length; j++)
            {
                //alert(aData[iBiggest].polygonpoints[j]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: either use <= then -1 or just < in your loop.

Comment: The javascript code you have written won't compile. It is not even syntactically correct. Can you please correct the code?

Comment: @user2069036 Why don't you start with `for (var i = 1`? Anyway, are you saying that if you put an alert inside the loop, it does show `iBiggest` correctly?

Comment: Is this code even syntactically correct? See the last line `for(var j=0; j`. Moreover see the loop `for(var i=0; i  (aData[iBiggest].polygonpoints.length))`, there is no comparison of `i` and `i` is not getting incremented.

Comment: Meine Fresse, was ein Feigling

Comment: @codingbuddha Und was hat ihr Mahlzeit damit zu tun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

```
   
      $.getJSON("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=pekin,+china&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1", function(data)
        {
            var iBiggest = 0;

            for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                if(data[i].polygonpoints != 'undefined' && data[i].polygonpoints)
                {
                    if((data[i].polygonpoints.length) > (data[iBiggest].polygonpoints.length))
                    {
                        iBiggest = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            alert(iBiggest);

            for(var j = 0; j < data[iBiggest].polygonpoints.length; j++)
            {
                alert(data[iBiggest].polygonpoints[j]);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is wrong, the array index will start from 0 to length - 1 so `i <= aData.length` is wrong.

So the loop should be

```
$
.get("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=london,+england&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1")
.done(function(data) {

    var iBiggest = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if ((data[i].polygonpoints.length) > (data[iBiggest].polygonpoints.length)) {
            iBiggest = i;
        }
    }

    // this is not working
    alert(iBiggest);

    for (var j = 0; j < data[iBiggest].polygonpoints.length; j++) {
        // alert(aData[iBiggest].polygonpoints[j]);
    }
}, 'json');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZzPLG/)

Comment: @user2069036 check your browser console to see whether are is any errors

Comment: @user2069036 can you also share the value of `data`

Comment: @user2069036 my code is right, yours is not working because the there is no data with index `10000`. You can see the alert in my fiddle

Comment: @user2069036 if you want a larger number for `iBiggest ` set it to `var iBiggest = data.length - 1;`

Comment: @user2069036 it is giving a alert saying `0` for me

Comment: @user2069036 which is the browser used

Comment: @user2069036 because `iBiggest` is set as `1000` and `aData.length` is 4 which means `aData[iBiggest].polygonpoints` will through an error

Comment: @user2069036 also `aJsonData = JSON.parse(data);` is not required since the data is already a json object. just set it as `aJsonData  = data`